# TypedArray ?android can't get proper value

Tags: android, android-progressbar, typedarray

This is what I want to achieve:

xml file

```
app:loaderStyle="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

code

```
int loaderStyle = loaderProperties.getResourceId(R.styleable.LoaderButton_loaderStyle,
            android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
...
mLoader = new ProgressBar(getContext(), null, loaderStyle);
```

but

```
loaderStyle != android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but I have to consume the style attribute. Maybe for someone it will be usefull. More advanced answers are welcome

xml file

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

code

```
mLoader = new ProgressBar(getContext(), null, mAttributeSet.getStyleAttribute());
```